# How to save current page stage when ionic app pause and restored when ionic app resume?

Tags: typescript, angular7, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app, i tried to make this app like when we killed app ,next time it will start their last killed stage. I know that pause and resume event for ionic. but which code using inside the pause and resume event to restored my last killed stage .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't like taking a snapshot of a virtual machine and then restarting it again later.

You get the Ionic events which give you the chance to save and restore data.

Redirecting to the appropriate page and setting the data back to its previous state is something you have to write yourself and is specific to each app.

Just think about the way that you set a page up when it's used normally and then apply those ideas to the resume event.

Comment: Sir , i'm new developer in this field. so that please can you give me examples related to your solution.

Comment: Sorry I dont have them. I have the impression that this feature doesn't do what you are actually wanting it to do anyway. I think this is just for pause and resume, so when you switch apps and you come back and its still there loaded. I think this functionality is just to do things like pause the game or stop a timer or stop the music playing like YouTube does.